# Are there any natural languages that actually have gender neutral 3rd person pronouns?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, gender

You see this a lot in the auxlang movement that having gendered pronouns is sexist.

But making conlangs of my own, I find its absence to be often annoying. No one seems to realize how useful it is to be able to use different pronouns to refer to different people. If you only have one, you're often forced to just refer to everyone by name or some kind of title. I imagine in the real world, a true gender-neutral pronoun would eventually vanish due to its definition being too broad. At the very least its use would diminish over time even if it did exist, thus making it relatively temporary.

Comment: Yes; in fact, the majority of natural languages have no gendered pronouns.

Comment: A prof at my undergrad told me about an Indigenous student he had once who had been homeschooled and was just mastering English. His language has no gender at all, and when he told his grandma about English requiring you to say "he" and "she" she exclaimed, "What? You have to point at someone's crotch just to talk about them?" Believe it or not, this can be considered extraneous info that isn't missed in other languages. Consider that some languages also have more genders, numbers, and persons in their pronoun systems and we don't miss that info.

Comment: Bantu languages tend to have gendered demonstratives and incorporated pronouns, but all humans are the same gender. Other genders are for plants, animals, concepts, inanimate objects…

Answer (score 4):

A lot. All Turkic languages (Turkish, Qazaq, Tatar, O'zbek, Sakha etc.), all Uralic languages (Finnish, Sami, Hungarian, Komi, Mari, Nenets etc.), a lot of Indo-Iranian langages (Persian, Sorani Kurdish, Bengali, Ossetic etc.), and many more. All the languages mentioned so far don't have grammatical gender, but even some languages with grammatical gender may fail to have gendered pronouns, for instance, Hindi-Urdu, and Kurmancî Kurdish in the absolutive case.

Comment: Don't forget Finnish. Also, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_neutrality_in_genderless_languages (feel free to add any of this to your answer if you like, of course—that's one of the things that comments are for).